# Populate table TD by ID when "select" changes in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, innerhtml

My task is to create a dynamic table which will be used to compare the services of different brokers againt each other in a table. Given by the websites size and clients requirements I need to be able to change to content of the table td's when the user makes a selection from the dropdown menu in the thanle header.

I've updated the code bellow with the latest version that I've put together till now.

The tasks I need help with are:

- Script only listens to col2
- How can I add an image to the array blogo?
- Have one item from the dropdown loaded by default per column eq Broker 1, Broker 2, Broker 3

**Table**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Comparison Chart Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="zebra" size="100%" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="center">Broker Vergleichsliste</th>
    <th>
        <select class="col2 selectBroker">
            <option>Broker 1</option>
            <option>Broker 2</option>
            <option>Broker 3</option>
            <option>Broker 4</option>
            <option>Broker 5</option>
        </select>
    </th>
    <th>
        <select class="col3 selectBroker">
            <option>Broker 1</option>
            <option>Broker 2</option>
            <option>Broker 3</option>
            <option>Broker 4</option>
            <option>Broker 5</option>
        </select>
    </th>
    <th>
        <select class="col4 selectBroker">
            <option>Broker 1</option>
            <option>Broker 2</option>
            <option>Broker 3</option>
            <option>Broker 4</option>
            <option>Broker 5</option>>
        </select>
    </th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><strong>Broker</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 blogo"></td>
    <td class="col3 blogo"></td>
    <td class="col4 blogo"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>Reguliert</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 regulated"></td>
    <td class="col3 regulated"></td>
    <td class="col4 regulated"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>securityicherheit</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 security"></td>
    <td class="col3 security"></td>
    <td class="col4 security"></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Verrechnungskonto</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 account"></td>
    <td class="col3 account"></td>
    <td class="col4 account"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Mindesteinlage</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 deposit"></td>
    <td class="col3 deposit"></td>
    <td class="col4 deposit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Software</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 software"></td>
    <td class="col3 software"></td>
    <td class="col4 software"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Handelseinheit</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 einheit"></td>
    <td class="col3 einheit"></td>
    <td class="col4 einheit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Margin Forex</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 margin"></td>
    <td class="col3 margin"></td>
    <td class="col4 margin"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Kommission pro Halfturn</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 comission"></td>
    <td class="col3 comission"></td>
    <td class="col4 comission"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Spreads</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 spread"></td>
    <td class="col3 spread"></td>
    <td class="col4 spread"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Finanzierungskosten</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 fcost"></td>
    <td class="col3 fcost"></td>
    <td class="col4 fcost"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Orderarten</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 orders"></td>
    <td class="col3 orders"></td>
    <td class="col4 orders"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Telefonhandel</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 phone"></td>
    <td class="col3 phone"></td>
    <td class="col4 phone"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Mobile Trading</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 mobile"></td>
    <td class="col3 mobile"></td>
    <td class="col4 mobile"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Produktpalette</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 products"></td>
    <td class="col3 products"></td>
    <td class="col4 products"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Besonderheiten</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 special"></td>
    <td class="col3 special"></td>
    <td class="col4 special"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>ECN / MM / STP / DMA</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 art"></td>
    <td class="col3 art"></td>
    <td class="col4 art"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Fazit</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 fazit"></td>
    <td class="col3 fazit"></td>
    <td class="col4 fazit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Zur Webseite</strong></td>
    <td class="center"><a href="/goto/forex/" target="_blank" class="button-more">Konto eröffnen</a></td>
    <td class="center"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="button-more">Konto eröffnen</a></td>
    <td class="center"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="button-more">Konto eröffnen</a></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var data = {
"brokers":
    {
    "broker": [
        {
        "name": "Broker 1",
        "blogo": "Broker1 Logo",
        "regulated": "YES",
        "security": "Mindep",
        "account": "Konto",
        "deposit": "Einlage",
        "software": "Software",
        "einheit": "H Einheit",
        "margin": "100:1",
        "comission": "Komission",
        "spread": "Spreads",
        "fcost": "F Kosten",
        "orders": "Orderarten",
        "phone": "YES/No",
        "mobile": "Yes/No",
        "products": "Products",
        "special": "Besonderheiten",
        "art": "MM/DMA",
        "fazit": "Fazit"
        },
    {
        "name": "Broker 2",
        "blogo": "Broker2 Logo",
        "regulated": "NO",
        "security": "Mindep",
        "account": "Konto",
        "deposit": "Einlage",
        "software": "Software",
        "einheit": "H Einheit",
        "margin": "200:1",
        "comission": "Komission",
        "spread": "Spreads",
        "fcost": "F Kosten",
        "orders": "Orderarten",
        "phone": "YES",
        "mobile": "Yes/No",
        "products": "Products",
        "special": "Besonderheiten",
        "art": "DMA/STP",
        "fazit": "Fazit"
        },
    {
        "name": "Broker 3",
        "blogo": "Broker3 Logo",
        "regulated": "YES",
        "security": "Mindep",
        "account": "Konto",
        "deposit": "Einlage",
        "software": "Software",
        "einheit": "H Einheit",
        "margin": "Forex margin",
        "comission": "Komission",
        "spread": "Spreads",
        "fcost": "F Kosten",
        "orders": "Orderarten",
        "phone": "NO",
        "mobile": "Yes/No",
        "products": "Products",
        "special": "Besonderheiten",
        "art": "ECN/MM/DMA",
        "fazit": "Fazit"
        },
    {
        "name": "Broker 4",
        "blogo": "Broker4 Logo",
        "regulated": "NO",
        "security": "Mindep",
        "account": "Konto",
        "deposit": "Einlage",
        "software": "Software",
        "einheit": "H Einheit",
        "margin": "Forex margin",
        "comission": "Komission",
        "spread": "Spreads",
        "fcost": "F Kosten",
        "orders": "Orderarten",
        "phone": "Green Tick",
        "mobile": "Yes/No",
        "products": "Products",
        "special": "Besonderheiten",
        "art": "MM/DMA",
        "fazit": "Fazit"
        },
    {
        "name": "Broker 5",
        "blogo": "Broker5 Logo",
        "regulated": "YES",
        "security": "Mindep",
        "account": "Konto",
        "deposit": "Einlage",
        "software": "Software",
        "einheit": "H Einheit",
        "margin": "Forex margin",
        "comission": "Komission",
        "spread": "Spreads",
        "fcost": "F Kosten",
        "mobile": "Yes/No",
        "products": "Products",
        "special": "Besonderheiten",
        "art": "ECN/STP",
        "fazit": "Fazit"
        }
    ]}
}

$(".selectBroker").change(function() {
var jthis = $(this);
var whichCol;
if (jthis.hasClass("col2")) {
    whichCol = "col2";
}
$.each(data.brokers.broker, function(i, v) {
    if (v.name == jthis.val()) {
        $("td." + whichCol + ".name").html(v.name);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".blogo").html(v.blogo);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".regulated").html(v.regulated);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".security").html(v.security);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".account").html(v.account);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".deposit").html(v.deposit);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".software").html(v.software);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".einheit").html(v.einheit);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".margin").html(v.margin);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".comission").html(v.comission);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".spread").html(v.spread);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".fcost").html(v.fcost);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".orders").html(v.orders);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".phone").html(v.phone);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".mobile").html(v.mobile);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".products").html(v.products);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".special").html(v.special);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".art").html(v.art);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".fazit").html(v.fazit);
        return;
    }
});

});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Normally when you're wracking your brain to do something never done before, it's because it's probably a bad idea.  Why not keep external data in an XML or JSON format?  You can always reconstruct the HTML from an XML or JSON data.  Heck, it can be done on the fly if you're also using XSLT with XML.  Also, does this have anything to do with Java?  Did you mean to tag it Javascript instead?

Comment: Hi @Neil, thanks for your reply. I suppose I was meant to tag it javascript, my bad. I would be happy to use a XML file if I would know how to go about it. I'm not a javascript or XML wizard like many others. It just seemed to be the right approach to try and do it via td class or, like it is right now. But I cant use txtarea to populate the cells. Any help appreciated

Comment: I think I've found teh way to go using getElementById and innerHtml. I'm just not sure how to go about adding it in the best way.

Comment: You simply have to set innerHtml to the string to change the dom.  To append, you do `element.innerHtml += appendedHtml`

Comment: @Neil thanks again. I've done some more  research and pretty close to have what I want. I've changed the fucntion to `function changeContent(which){document.getElementById("blogo").innerHTML = brokerlogo[which.selectedIndex];}` the table td with the id _blogo_ now displays the text from brokerlogo[0]. I'm stuck now fixing up `document.bv24compare.blogo.value=brokerlogo[document.bv24compare.selectbox.selectedIndex]`to call the next item in the array when there is a selection change. Any suggestion?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your goal. Are you trying to change what rows are visible or what information is visible when selecting broker abc?

Comment: @Eonasdan I'm trying to change the info displayed in each td depending on the selection from the dropdown. I've just updated my original question with my latest changes. This is killing me... been reading into this for days now.

Comment: ah. yes I see now. so if column1 has brokerA then all of the rows in that column should show Yes/No. Does column2 have to be aware that column1 has brokerA selected?

Comment: @Eonasdan the columns dont need to listen to each other. Each of them is individual. Let's say you display broker1 - broker4 in the table then each column should return the info only relevant to that broker and dynamically change if another broker is selected. The shown info goes from plain text to broker logo or "green tick" and "red X". I have a list with the details that need to be shown in each column related to the row title on the left of the table. I already see a problem with the current array since I don't belive I can use the ID blogo on each cell but instead it's unique.

Comment: I'm thinking of trying to use `brokerlogo.b1[0]` instead now for the selector. New land for me here. Never had to solve something like this.

Comment: You could just use a JSON model that had the details of each broker in it. when the select is changed go find the broker in the array. set the info for each td `td.isTotalyAwesome` from `data.broker[0].isTotalyAwesome`

Comment: each td needs an id or class or that you always know which cell belongs to which row and what info that cell is supposed to display

Comment: @Eonasdan I'm not sure I can follow. could you provide me with a tiny sample of the JSON model and adressing the td id? I would very much appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/gqQ77/4/). You'll need to expand it of course to finish the code. There are probably better ways to do this but it works and it was something I banged out in a few minutes.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <select class="col1 selectBroker">
                <option>Broker 1</option>
                <option>Broker 2</option>
                <option>Broker 3</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th>
            <select class="col2 selectBroker">
                <option>Broker 1</option>
                <option>Broker 2</option>
                <option>Broker 3</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th>
            <select class="col3 selectBroker">
                <option>Broker 1</option>
                <option>Broker 2</option>
                <option>Broker 3</option>
            </select>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1 isTotallyAwesome"></td>
        <td class="col2 isTotallyAwesome"></td>
        <td class="col3 isTotallyAwesome"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1 foo"></td>
        <td class="col2 foo"></td>
        <td class="col3 foo"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var data = {
    "brokers":
        {
        "broker": [
            {
            "name": "Broker 1",
            "isTotallyAwesome": "yes",
            "foo": "no"},
        {
            "name": "Broker 2",
            "isTotallyAwesome": "no",
            "foo": "yes"},
        {
            "name": "Broker 3",
            "isTotallyAwesome": "true",
            "foo": "no"}
        ]}
}

$(".selectBroker").change(function() {
    var jthis = $(this);
    var whichCol;
    if (jthis.hasClass("col1")) {
        whichCol = "col1";
    }
    $.each(data.brokers.broker, function(i, v) {
        if (v.name == jthis.val()) {
            $("td." + whichCol + ".isTotallyAwesome").html(v.isTotallyAwesome);
            $("td." + whichCol + ".foo").html(v.foo);
            return;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: this is great thanks very much! Only two questions remain maybe you can help me? 1: Can I still have a broker selected by default on each row using <option selected>`and how can I add an image to the broker data aray?

Comment: you could break some of the functionality of the `.change` into its own function and then just call that at page load, or you could just set that data initial to the table. as to your second question jquery can change the `src` of an image, just look that up and add the source to the data array.

Comment: please up vote and accept this as the answer since it helped you.

Comment: Hi @Eonasdan. Thanks again for your help. I was going to up the answer but need a couple more reputation point. I will up it though for sure. As for the implementation, I'm having issues adding more columns ot the var data array. For some reason it throws an expcetion in dreamweaver the moment I add them though I've set the td's and added another `$("td." + whichCol + ".new").html(v.new);
' - However, I will work it out from here and thank you for your time. ;)

Comment: take your array and copying it into [json lint)[http://jsonlint.com/] it will help validate your json. You should be able to accept this as the answer at least

Comment: I voted yoru answer up - I copied your array to JSONLint which already gives me an error in line one. But again, I'm a lot further now than I was yesterday. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the initial question with the latest progress.

Comment: @Eonsadan wasn't aware that you're still following this question. Yes I have a few issues of the JS only listeing to col2 and of course loading an image via the array.

Comment: you need to add `if/else` statements for each column

Comment: @Eonsadan. thanks again will look at the docu  on if/else statements. I will continue working on this tomorrow and also updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HammerMan/gqQ77/6/). little late here. ;)

Comment: @Eonsadan - Made some great progress thanks to your help. I've updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HammerMan/ddXYt/22/) with the latest code and almost there now. Thank you!